# Error on creating Rails new project (../config/boot (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting this error on Rails new project setup.  Any clue?

```
$rails new my_project
    /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/ankit/config/boot (LoadError)
       from /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
       from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem (using rails 4) and found out that the rails command was thinking that the current directory was an existing rails project, because the file `/bin/rails` existed (outside of RVM). You can check this by running `which -a rails`. Moving the executable (binstub?) out of the way fixed the issue.